# How to Return a Observable value if its not null otherwise call an http service and return the data?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
@Injectable()

/***
 * Service for manage profile
 */
export class ManageProfileService {

    private UserDetails: any = null;
    public GetUserDetails$: Observable<any>
}
```

I want to subscribe the GetUserDetails  Observable from the service and it should return if the value of UserDetails is not null then return the UserDetails variable value otherwise call an HTTP service "getUserDetails" and return the data what gets from the service, if HTTP service if failed it should return null. please any help to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RxJS [`of`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of) function to return the variable `UserDetails` as an observable.

Try the following

Service

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ManageProfileService {
  private UserDetails: any = null;

  public getUserDetails(): Observable<any> {
    return (!!this.UserDetails) ? of(this.UserDetails) : this.http.get('url');
  }
}
```

You could then subscribe in the component

Component

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.manageProfileService.getUserDetails().subscribe(
      res => {
        // res - `this.manageProfileService.UserDetails` if it's defined
        // res - response from `http.get('url')` if not
      },
      err => { }
    );
  }
}
```